# Md-tab freezing when ng-click is called

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I asked for help a few days ago for why is my ng-repeat so slow and I managed to figure it out why. I have 3 md-tabs with ng-clicks on them to refresh my data on click, the problem is the ng-click is executed before the tab changes which is causing a little freezing. Tried to use md-on-select, it causes the same issue.

Used a for loop just to demonstrate the issue, in my case where is freezing I use a http get..

Made a jsfiddle to help you guys out: https://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/vvstgg4g/3/

My HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selected_tab">
        <md-tab label="zero" ng-click="load(0)">
           <md-content class="md-padding">
             <div ng-show="selected_tab == 0">
               <div ng-include="'list1.html'"></div>
             </div>
           </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="one" ng-click="load(1)">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
               <div ng-show="selected_tab == 1">
                  <div ng-include="'list2.html'"></div>
               </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="two" ng-click="load(2)">
           <md-content class="md-padding">
               <div ng-show="selected_tab == 2">
                   <div ng-include="'list3.html'"></div>
               </div>
           </md-content>
        </md-tab>
     </md-tabs>

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="list1.html">
    <div ng-if="showSpinner" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
       <p></p>
       <md-progress-circular ng-if="showSpinner" md-diameter="70">      </md-progress-circular>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in default_list">
       <p>{{item.test}}</p>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="list3.html">
     <div ng-if="showSpinner" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
     <p></p>
        <md-progress-circular ng-if="showSpinner" md-diameter="70"></md-progress-circular>
     </div>
     <div ng-repeat="item in default_list">
         <p>{{item.test}}</p>
     </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="list2.html">
     <div ng-if="showSpinner" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
         <p></p>
         <md-progress-circular ng-if="showSpinner" md-diameter="70"></md-progress-circular>
     </div>
     <div ng-repeat="item in default_list">
         <p>{{item.test}}</p>
     </div>
  </script>
```

And my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial']);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope","$rootScope", "$mdDialog","$mdPanel",'$filter', '$http', function($scope, $rootScope, $mdDialog, $mdPanel, $filter, $http){

  $scope.default_list = [];

    $scope.list0 = [{test:"test111"}, {test2:"test2"}, {test3:"test3"}];
    $scope.list1 = [{test:"test222"}, {test2:"test2"}, {test3:"test3"}];
    $scope.list2 = [{test:"test333"}, {test2:"test2"}, {test3:"test3"}];

  $scope.load = function(selected){
    for(var i= 0; i < 2000; i++){
        console.log("test");
    }
    $scope.showSpinner = true;
    $http.get('/echo/json').then(function(value) {
        $scope.showSpinner = false;
            if(selected == 0){
               $scope.default_list = $scope.list0;
            }else if(selected == 1){
               $scope.default_list = $scope.list1;
            }else if(selected == 2){
               $scope.default_list = $scope.list2;
            }
        });
     }

     $scope.load(0);

   }
]);
```

Does this have a solution or is this currently a bug ?